# The best and safety way to pass in extern function as a parameter a function of class without boost?

Tags: c++, function, function-pointers

I've the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

typedef void ( *FuncPtr )( int );

extern void MyFunc( FuncPtr callback )    

class MyClass
{
public:
    void SomeFunction( int n )
    {
        std::cout << "bla: " << n << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    MyClass obj;
    MyFunc( /*  */ );
}
```

What is the best and safety way to pass in `MyFunc` function as a parameter a function of class without (`SomeFunction`) boost?

Comment: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html

Comment: Declare `SomeFunction` as `static`.

Comment: Is the question "how do you pass a pointer to member function as a function parameter"?

Answer (score 2):

You can't, and even if your compiler allows it, I'm sure you'd get into undefined behavior.

`SomeFunction` is not like a free function, it is a member function. That means it operates on an object, so calling it outside of context is a sure path to disaster.

Answer (score 2):

The idiom for C callbacks is to include *user data* which passes an arbitrary parameter through the function and back into the callback:

```
typedef void ( *FuncPtr )( int, uintptr_t user_data );

extern void MyFunc( FuncPtr callback, uintptr_t user_data );
```

When invoking a method on a class with a callback you use the `user_data` to pass the `this` pointer:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    void SomeFunction( int n )
    {
        std::cout << "bla: " << n << std::endl;
    }
private:
    static void SomeFunctionEntry( int n, uintptr_t user_data)
    {
        MyClass *ths = (MyClass *) user_data;
        ths->SomeFunction(n);
    }
};
```

The static function `SomeFunctionEntry` is a free function which can be invoked as a callback.  You ensure its `user_data` argument is a valid class instance:

```
int main()
{
    MyClass obj;
    MyFunc(&MyClass::SomeFunctionEntry, (uintptr_t) &obj);
}
```

(side note:  it is a **very bad idea** to pass an automatic variable like `obj` as a callback in a multithreaded environment because it is difficult to be sure that the pointer will still be valid when the callback is eventually invoked)

Comment: +1 complete answer, even the classic "very bad idea" is in there :)